# Can I combine two developmentally-graded scales into one dependent variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling, data-transformation, psychology

I want to look at depressive symptoms in autism. I have a sample of adolescents and adults with autism spectrum disorders, 49 of whom received the Beck Depression Inventory (BDI) and 6 of whom got the Children's Depression Inventory (CDI; also written by Beck).

It is such a small sample that I don't want to throw away the six subjects because they got a different depression measure, but I can't find any precedent for combining two developmentally-graded measures of the same construct into one dependent variable. Does anyone know (1) if I can, and (2) how to do so?